# Pixelated lock and home screens after wake up on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: suspend, lock-screen

On Ubuntu 19.04, I am facing a strange issue. Generally when I am not working, I don't always shutdown my laptop. I simply close the lid and that's it. 
When I log back in to do something, I am mostly greeted with a pixelated lock screen and subsequently with a pixelated home screen (look at the wallpaper) as you can see in the image below.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea of what's going on? I've never faced such issues on earlier versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this could be the same issue as described on [gnome-shell#1809407](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1809407). A fix seems to be in progress in [upstream mutter](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/merge_requests/600/commits).